# Installing windows 7 on virtual Box in my Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: sudo, su

Helo there,, while am installing windows 7 on  virtual box in my ubuntu is it a must that i have a flashdisk or i can just choose the iso file directly?

Comment: When installing Windows to VM in VBox I just select New, then Create..., then VDI..., Then Start the VM and at "Select start-up disk" select the Windows ISO.

Answer (score 1):

You can install from iso, mount it with the optical drive of the virtual machine

[image]

An ISO file can be mounted in virtual optical drive